# Magento 1.9.2 Navigation menu not working on live server but working on local server

Tags: magento-1.9

I have a strange problem. I am working on Magento 1.9.2 locally on XAMPP Server. Everything was working properly on `locahost or 127.0.0.1` including the navigation menu which we create by the help of adding categories.  Root categories -> Sub Categories. 
Yesterday, i have uploaded my website to live testing server. Everything is working properly except the nav menu at the top is not working which contains the categories. I am trying to solve this problem since long time but nothing helped.  i am using RWD theme with custom folder in it. I use Custom folder to customize the website which is a proper way to do customization. 
I have used one extension named WP_Custom_Menu from official magestore. I have tried disabling and enabling this extension on live server but nothing happen. If anyone have encountered this issue ever or know how to fix it. please provide me guidance.

Answer (score 0):

Check the naming of your Templates and Folders  - particularly the case used in filenames. Often servers have case-sensitive filesystems whereas your XAMPP install may not.

I've spent hours tracking down issues before, only to discover files missing a capital letter or similar.

Comment: Hi, i am still having the same problem. Navigation menu is not showing. But after changing theme from rwd/custom to base/default or rwd/default navigation menu appears on the screen. So, it means that i am having problem in custom folder which i have created for modifying and customizing the rwd/default theme. But i am still unable to figure out what is the issue. what should be the issue i don't know please help